# Iris Dataset Using Logistic Regression backend (TensorFlow 2.1.0)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

```
        ###################### Module 1 ##############
# Begin building the model framework
# Declare the variables that need to be learned and initialization
# There are 4 features here, A's dimension is (4, 1)

tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

A = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal(shape=[4, 1]), name = "Weight")
       
b = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal(shape=[1, 1]), name = "bias")

init = tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer()

sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()

sess.run(init)

                      # STATUS(Module 1) = NO ERROR**

######################## Module 2 ############################

# Define placeholders
data = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 4])          
target = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 1])

                  # STATUS(Module 2) = NO ERROR**

####################### Module 3 ########################

#define mod

mod = tf.matmul(data, A) + b 

   
                            
                     # STATUS(Module 3) = NO ERROR**

 ####################### **Module 4** #############################

# define loss
                                                                     
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = mod, labels = target))

                  # STATUS(Module 4) = NO ERROR**

######################### Module 5 ################################

learning_rate = 0.003

batch_size = 30  
                                                 
iter_num = 1500

                  # STATUS(Module 5) = NO ERROR**

######################## Module 6 ##############################

# Define the optimizer
opt = tf.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate)  
                       
                       # STATUS(Module 6) = NO ERROR**

########################### **Module 7** ###########################

# Define goal
goal = opt.minimize(loss, var_list=[A,b]) 
                           
                     # STATUS(Module 7) = ERROR**
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-2a1611d0ffdd> in <module>
      1 # Define goal
----> 2 goal = opt.minimize(loss, var_list=[A,b])

/opt/conda/envs/Python-3.7-main/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py in minimize(self, loss, var_list, grad_loss, name)
    314     """
    315     grads_and_vars = self._compute_gradients(
--> 316         loss, var_list=var_list, grad_loss=grad_loss)
    317 
    318     return self.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars, name=name)

/opt/conda/envs/Python-3.7-main/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py in _compute_gradients(self, loss, var_list, grad_loss)
    348       if not callable(var_list):
    349         tape.watch(var_list)
--> 350       loss_value = loss()
    351     if callable(var_list):
    352       var_list = var_list()

TypeError: **'Tensor' object is not callable**
```

Please find 7 modules above; I am getting error in module 7
probably there is something missing in module 4 i.e while defining (loss function) and it might not be linked with optimizer.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the optimizer

```
opt = tf.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate)
```

by

```
opt = tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
```